# what is the limit of allocating memory using pci_alloc_consistent?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

why do i get a kernel crash of `cpuacct_charge` when i try to allocate 600 blocks of 2 MB memory using -  `pci_alloc_consistent` , is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: `cpuacct_charge` is not related to memory allocation. How much memory does this machine have? What do you need this memory for?

Comment: i have 6 Giga free , and 8 overall, i need for some pci device i'm using

Comment: PCI or PCIe? Do the device and the host bridge support dual address cycles?

Comment: pcie , kmalloc also fails..

Comment: i have no idea why it matters , but somekind of network card

Comment: How can you write a driver for hardware you do not know?

Comment: it is Ethernet card.. still under development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to allocate memory using `__get_free_pages()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running out of 32-bit-addressable memory.

If your PCIe chip actually supports larger addresses, your driver should use `dma_set_mask` and `dma_set_consistent_mask` to tell the kernel about this.
(See `Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt`.)

Comment: we already do that and i am using 64 bit mask.. still unable to allocate more than 600Mb

Comment: Check with `dma_get_mask`.

Comment: i am even crashing when using kmalloc after about 800MB of allocation for some reason, any ideas ? , and my dma mask is 64 bits also... i just checked with the dma_get_mask

Comment: maybe i should use __get_free_pages ?